# Which Event is fired? (javascript, input-field-history)

Tags: javascript

I have a text field which is empty, but when you click in it it has some suggestions from previous inputs.

Which JavaScript event is fired if i choose one of them with the mouse?

i'm using jquery 1.6.2 for binding the listeners:

```
view.textRegistrations.bind("blur change keyup", function(event) {
    //do Something
});
```

Comment: What browser is this? I do not think it has anything to do with javascript...

Comment: None. You can't track the suggestions from an input field! This would be a big privacy issue

Comment: @neal: i'm using firefox

Comment: I don't think this is something you can tap into. It the "autocomplete" list that the browser keeps tracks of

Comment: @MichaelWalter: i dont want to track the sugestions... i want to track when one is chosen.

Comment: I've understanded this. But if you could the one you could do the other. It's only the explanation why you can't check, if someone is selected. you could try something around with onchange="" on the element. you can check if the elemtent gets some new characters after a click (not key press to avoid ctrl+v)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the oninput event triggered.

try:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form method="get" id="" action="">
                <input type="text" name="name" oninput="alert('oninput')"/>
                <input type="submit" value="done"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

the diffrence between oninput,onpropertychange,onchange:

**onchange** fired only when

a）the property changed by user interface

b）and the element lost focus

**onpropertychange** fires when property change. but it is IE only

**oninput**

oninput is the W3C version of onpropertychange . IE9 begin surport this event .

oninput fired only when the element value changes.

so if you want compacity in all browsers

IE<9 use onpropertychange

IE>9 and other broweser use oninput

if you use jQuery , you can bind two event that share the same hander

```
$(function($) {
  //the same handler
  function oninput(e){
    //do sth
  }

  $("#ipt").on("input", function(e){
    console.log("trigger by oninput");
    oninput(e);
  })

  $("#ipt").on("propertychange", function(e) {
    console.log("trigger by propertychange");
    oninput(e);
  })
})
```

demo at http://output.jsbin.com/salekaconi

Comment: This works in Chrome, seems to behave like onchange in Firefox

Comment: since i'm using jquery, i just needed to add input to my event-list

Answer (score 1):

An incredibly useful tool that should help you solve your problem is [Visual Event 2](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2). Basically, for any element on your screen, it will tell you which Javascript evenets that element is registered for.

It's a bookmarklet, so what you do is drag this the to your bookmarks bar, navigate to the page you're curious about, and then click then link. Presto! Detailed information about the currently registered Javascript events.

As @smerny said, there's a good chance that's not even Javascript, and is just native browser functionality. That being said, you could probably implement your own version pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The *input* event reports a change (I'm testing with *Google Chrome v28*), [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8hm/1/)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].oninput = function (e) {
    console.log('input', e);
};
```

But at the same time, `monitorEvents` from console doesn't report any event when it happens

```
monitorEvents(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]);
```

Apply in console on [**this page**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nm8hm/show/) for example