# Is there a trigger for selecting a value from previous user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I have an input text field. My Browser shows me previous values of this input field and I can select one of them. Is there a trigger for this event?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you say trigger, do you mean an event that's raised when the previous values are shown? If so, no. If you mean an event when one is selected, then yes - use `input`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I mean the event when a value is selected

Comment: Then yep, `input` is what you need. But don't use an `on*` event attribute like the below answer suggests; it's not 1997 any more.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. would you turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748876/which-event-is-fired-javascript-input-field-history) might help you. Writer has explained it well.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate of the answer @TechnoTech linked to, just be aware  that you should use `on()`, not `bind()`

Comment: thanks. yes the input-event does exactly what I wanted. And of course I am using .on("input"....)

Answer (score 0):

You can use event `onchange="myFunction()"`. it will fire when you change the value of the field